# preview image sequence composite

Tags: compositing-nodes, image

I'm compositing an image sequence in blender, and would like to preview it while working.
image editor shows only a still image, and I don't want to export every time I wish to preview.
Is it possible to preview an image sequence while working (like after effect's ram preview?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. Do you want the image sequence to update the displayed frame on frame changes?

Comment: @gandalf3 I think he wants to playback the image sequence he is compositing without having to render to disk everytime he wants a preview. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3385/12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While compositing, RenderLayer doesn't move with time](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3363/12). For a somewhat faster alternative than your current workflow, see [Can the compositor be used to batch process images?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15755/12).

Comment: Using Blender's compositor is there is no RAM preview like there is on AfterFX.

Comment: You can buffer in RAM by adding the scene strip (that contains the comp) to a VSE timeline, Then in Timeline (not VSE) turn Playback button to No Sync. After a play through Blender has buffered and will continue to play at full frame rate. If it continues to stutter along reduce the VSE scene resolution or increase your VSE memory buffer in User Prefs.

Answer (score 2):

In the VSE preview window that the cube appears in press <kbd>N</kbd> for Properties and deselect the OpenGL Render. You should see the compositor output. If not, go back to the VSE window and press the Refresh Sequencer Button.

Comment: you're awesome! thank you so much! just made my life a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Set up the VSE and add the compositor scene as a trip. This will buffer if you play back with AV sync set to off in the timeline. After playing once the rendered RAM buffered animation will playback at full speed. You can run out of memory this way, increase the Sequencer memory in User Prefs. And you can reduce the VSE scene scale to render smaller frames.

Comment: how do I add the compositor scene as a strip, I can only choose the scene from the viewport or import footage. (the scene was rendered in maya, so only the image sequence is present on my blend file.

Comment: Open the VSE, you can use the same scene as the the compositor if you wish. Make sure that the scene properties allow Compositing and the VSE for Post Processing.Place your timeline indicator (the play bar) at the start and press Shift A to add media. Select Scene > Scene (name of comp scene). Blender will drop the scene as a strip on your VSE timeline.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate explanation.
I'm probably doing something wrong though.
when I add a new strip-> scene all I'm seeing is the default cube from my 3d view and not the compositor
(image for example) http://i265.photobucket.com/albums/ii201/cymps/CompositorPreview.png